# Change SVG overlay through external CSS

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

How do you change an svg color within a button on :hover state by targeting the image path eg /img/example.svg ?

I.e.

The color of svg is grey as per "example.svg" stored in /img/example.svg

On hover it changes the color from grey to white by not having the .svg inline but targeting it through the img folder path. The svg is not inline in the html document.

For the example below i've added it to the HTML, but need to target the image file not within HTML for this example.

Attached is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/eofst39x/1/

**HTML**

```
     <br>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="btn btn-sm btn-nav-top">
            <svg  version="1.1" id="svg-overlay" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#b1b1b1" d="M27.297,4.902c-6.134-6.176-16.112-6.21-22.289-0.076c-6.177,6.134-6.209,16.112-0.077,22.289
    c6.135,6.176,16.113,6.21,22.29,0.076C33.397,21.057,33.43,11.079,27.297,4.902z M22.941,4.171l-3.343,3.32
    c-2.208-0.902-4.695-0.911-6.909-0.024L9.369,4.124C13.57,1.742,18.757,1.76,22.941,4.171z M7.574,19.434l-3.343,3.32
    c-2.383-4.201-2.365-9.389,0.047-13.574l3.321,3.343C6.696,14.731,6.688,17.22,7.574,19.434z M9.287,27.846l3.344-3.32
    c2.207,0.902,4.696,0.911,6.909,0.024l3.32,3.343C18.66,30.275,13.471,30.258,9.287,27.846z M21.13,21.06
    c-2.786,2.766-7.301,2.75-10.068-0.035c-2.766-2.785-2.75-7.301,0.036-10.067s7.301-2.751,10.067,0.034S23.916,18.293,21.13,21.06z
     M24.63,19.493c0.902-2.208,0.912-4.696,0.024-6.91l3.343-3.32c2.382,4.2,2.365,9.388-0.047,13.574L24.63,19.493z"/>
</svg>
            Recolor This SVG on Left</div>
    </a>
<br>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-nav-top { 
  color: #BBBBBB; 
  background-color: #FFFFFF; 
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100; 
}
.btn-nav-top img { 
    width: 15px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}  

.btn-nav-top:hover {
    transition: 0.2s;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #EE2798; 

}

.btn-nav-top:hover {
    fill: #ffffff;       
}

.btn-nav-top:focus, 
.btn-nav-top:active, 
.btn-nav-top.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-nav-top { 
  color: #BBBBBB; 
  background-color: #c10b75; 
  border-color: #BBBBBB; 
} 

.btn-nav-top:active, 
.btn-nav-top.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-nav-top { 
  background-image: none; 
  color: #fff;
} 

.btn-nav-top.disabled, 
.btn-nav-top[disabled], 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-nav-top, 
.btn-nav-top.disabled:hover, 
.btn-nav-top[disabled]:hover, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-nav-top:hover, 
.btn-nav-top.disabled:focus, 
.btn-nav-top[disabled]:focus, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-nav-top:focus, 
.btn-nav-top.disabled:active, 
.btn-nav-top[disabled]:active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-nav-top:active, 
.btn-nav-top.disabled.active, 
.btn-nav-top[disabled].active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-nav-top.active { 
  background-color: #FFFFFF; 
  border-color: #BBBBBB; 
} 

.btn-nav-top .badge { 
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  background-color: #BBBBBB; 
}

#svg-overlay svg:hover {
    fill: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not work across document boundaries.  So if the CSS is on the HTML side, it cannot affect the  SVG, if the SVG is in a separate file.

However you can add a `<style>` element to your SVG, that has your hover rules.  This should work as long as you are including the SVG using `<object>` or `<embed>`.  It won't work if you are using `<img>` or `background-image` though.

Comment: Is that inside the svg or html?